# Not Able to Extract Full details/data from a JSON File in Unity C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, text

I'm trying to access data from JSON file though i am only able to extract the name while others aren't showing. I have attached both my JSON file and my C# script from unity. The Item Class list data which needs to be extracted from the JSON file i.e name, gameId, message etc.

What is Captured when running.

[image]

Here is my code - JSONreader

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JSONreader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset txtJson;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class ItemList
    {

        public Item item;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Item
    {
        public string name;
        public string request;
        public string key;
        public string value;
        public string raw;
        public string type;
        public string header;
        public string gameId;
        public float amount;
        public string orderId;
        public int code;
        public string message;
        public string transactionId;
        public string description;
        
    }

    public ItemList itemList = new ItemList();

    private void Start()
    {
        itemList = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemList>(txtJson.text);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

my JSON file

```
{
        "name": "Purchase API",
        "protocolProfileBehavior": {
            "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                "accept": true,
                "user-agent": true
            }
        },

        "request": {
            "auth": {
                "type": "bearer",
                "bearer": [
                    {
                        "key": "token",
                        "value": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InIxTGtiQm8zOTI1UmIyWkZGckt5VTNNVmV4OVQyODE3S3gwdmJpNmlfS2MifQ.eyJuYW1lIjoiU2FtcGxlIEFkbWluIFVzZXIiLCJuaWNrbmFtZSI6InRoZWFkbWluIiwiYmlvIjpudWxsLCJzdWIiOiI0MTk0NjEzYi02MTI0LTQyN2UtODk2NC0yYWY1ZGNiM2UzZjIiLCJub25jZSI6IjEyMyIsInNfaGFzaCI6ImpTUFBiSWJvTktlcWJ0N1ZUQ2JPS3ciLCJhdWQiOiJmNGQ3MTE4YS1iY2UyLTExZWMtOTliNC05ZWI3NDRmNWJiZTIiLCJleHAiOjE2NTM5MzQ1MDQsImlhdCI6MTY1MzkzMDkwNCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZC5qaXdlLmlvIn0.tquqwYt8htiZd27au4R4H6Zjd1VqzNJGw5xZCEQ8NRlrQvmudUz-uo4qdHNW9k71w6Di3H-qMdliuFgj7sJb0naDNIScEalw1xPlA0R8QyIB6JT8YFiAANAfYvIaM4DWYeagDdia3MXJoRnnWxgg57yzd-ZA_ws3-brh-I-1mulRiGQcZ8wgpRhk4Vp3xjvNa3FcsyJ7excPTiD5zaSdtKGSJ3J2RSOAt5n2m-R-QGe_1lwAXXR-sa7P77tyG4FmQ2gHtmCRRnZzVD0AM6fULYWwYURARTwiCki2HYWCNJsMplID99Hx5JOHzwViHtV6XioRelk0t3Gef7Jqd2gYqg",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },

            "method": "POST",
            "header": [
                {
                    "key": "api_secret",
                    "value": "5e3ca84dad0758595a8dc793beb509505e79998bac87ffde128c668ac0215a1ed0462407ac794e99b26041cc3eab266cd06ced0d530b6d02d024d6b49353dd8d",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "key": "api_key",
                    "value": "hasuraengine",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ],

            "body": {
                "mode": "raw",
                "raw": "{\n    \"gameId\": \"JiweGameID\",\n    \"amount\": 1,\n    \"orderId\": \"OrderID Generated On GameDev Side\",\n    \"description\": \"Charlie's Test\",\n    \"applyTransactionFeeOn\": \"SENDER\",\n    \"idempotencyKey\": \"SOME_KEY#2\",\n    \"metadata\": {\n        \"key\": \"value\"\n    }\n}",
                "options": {
                    "raw": {
                        "language": "json"
                    }
                }
            },

            "url": {
                "raw": "https://bursment.jiwe.io/api/v1/cowrie/purchases",
                "protocol": "https",
                "host": [
                    "bursment",
                    "jiwe",
                    "io"
                ],
                "path": [
                    "api",
                    "v1",
                    "cowrie",
                    "purchases"
                ]
            }
        },

        "response": [
            {
                "name": "Purchase API",
                "originalRequest": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "api_secret",
                            "value": "5e3ca84dad0758595a8dc793beb509505e79998bac87ffde128c668ac0215a1ed0462407ac794e99b26041cc3eab266cd06ced0d530b6d02d024d6b49353dd8d",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "api_key",
                            "value": "hasuraengine",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ],

                    "body": {
                        "mode": "raw",
                        "raw": "{\n    \"gameId\": \"JiweGameID\",\n    \"amount\": 1,\n    \"orderId\": \"OrderID Generated On GameDev Side\",\n    \"description\": \"Charlie's Test\",\n    \"applyTransactionFeeOn\": \"SENDER\",\n    \"idempotencyKey\": \"SOME_KEY#2\",\n    \"metadata\": {\n        \"key\": \"value\"\n    }\n}",
                        "options": {
                            "raw": {
                                "language": "json"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    "url": {
                        "raw": "https://bursment.jiwe.io/api/v1/cowrie/purchases",
                        "protocol": "https",
                        "host": [
                            "bursment",
                            "jiwe",
                            "io"
                        ],

                        "path": [
                            "api",
                            "v1",
                            "cowrie",
                            "purchases"
                        ]
                    }
                },

                "status": "OK",
                "code": 200,
                "_postman_previewlanguage": "json",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Server",
                        "value": "nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Date",
                        "value": "Mon, 30 May 2022 18:40:17 GMT"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Length",
                        "value": "135"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Connection",
                        "value": "keep-alive"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Vary",
                        "value": "Origin"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Rate-Limit-Remaining",
                        "value": "53"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Rate-Limit-Reset",
                        "value": "1653936052"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Rate-Limit-Total",
                        "value": "60"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-DNS-Prefetch-Control",
                        "value": "off"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-Frame-Options",
                        "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Strict-Transport-Security",
                        "value": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-Download-Options",
                        "value": "noopen"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
                        "value": "nosniff"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
                        "value": "1; mode=block"
                    }
                ],
                
                "cookie": [],
                "body": "{\n    \"code\": \"200\",\n    \"type\": \"SUCCESS\",\n    \"message\": \"Purchase successful\",\n    \"transactionId\": \"f3a4ff6c-e047-11ec-80ac-000d3a9bae12\"\n}"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Your code claims `request` is a string while it’s an object. The format must match.

Comment: how would i know if this is an object or a string?

Comment: Look at the JSON

Comment: If it would say `"request" : "requestcontent"`, then `request` would be a string. In this case however, there is a `{` after the colon, indicating that an object will follow. So you'll have to make an object which can hold the data contained in the json, and make that the type of your request.

Comment: You can use this online C# class generator to have it generate the classes for you: https://json2csharp.com/